# Get pointer to Python int (in iteration)

Tags: cython

I'm binding to a C API that takes an array of structs (as `ATTRIBUTE *attributes`).

```
ctypedef struct ATTRIBUTE:
    unsigned long type
    void *pValue
    unsigned long ulValueLen
```

The C API assumes you're creating the struct array and its values on the stack before you call the function.

I can assign `pValue` as a one-off using:

```
cdef unsigned long value = True
attr.pValue = &value
```

However in this case we're taking values from Python (as an iterable). It appears to work okay for `bytes`.

```
data = PyMem_Malloc(len(attrs) * sizeof(ATTRIBUTE))

for index, (key, value) in enumerate(attrs.items()):
    data[index].type = key
    data[index].pValue = <unsigned char *> value
    data[index].ulValueLen = len(value)
```

However I have no stack definition to pass an integer type. What's the correct way to handle this? Do I need to also allocate arrays for other types I need to store and copy values into them, or can I access the underlying Python storage somehow?

Answer (score 0):

You can do both.

If you want to get the address of a Python object you use id() function. Then it is a matter of hackery how to cast it to a reference or pointer. But it should be doable. Note that Python's id() doesn't have to be exact with C stack, although it probably is. I do not know, you should check.  If not, some operations should get you the C stack address from it.

I never needed such a stuff from cython's endpoint.

Or you can grab for the locals() dictionary and enter its C structure to snatch out the pointer to Python's instance of the int in question.

I.e. In the end it will be a structure in C.

If you need to grab a pointer to the int instance from Python's side. You can employ tricks like you suggested or use id() to get the address, then use ctypes to grab it.
Exactly how to get to whole C struct is  a matter of thinking. Whether to read mem block, then use struct.unpack() and then use some other stuff to convert it into Pythonic representation of original. Perhaps ctypes would let you do it directly and you would get ctypes.Structure().

I didn't play with it (yet) so these are only my ideas. I hope helpful ones. In theory, based on my knowledge, they should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

My best solution so far is to store a set of results to `struct.pack` and pass those in.

```
try:
    attrs = dict(attrs)
    count = len(attrs)

    cdef ATTRIBUTE *data = <ATTRIBUTE *> PyMem_Malloc(count * sizeof(ATTRIBUTE))
    if not data:
        raise MemoryError()

    # Turn the values into bytes and store them so we have pointers
    # to them.
    _values = [
        # Real code is more interesting here
        value if isinstance(value, bytes) else struct.pack('L', value)
        for value in self.attrs.values()
    ]

    for index, (key, value) in enumerate(zip(attrs.keys(), self._values)):
        data[index].type = key
        data[index].pValue = <unsigned char *> value
        data[index].ulValueLen = len(value)

    doCall(data, count)

finally:
    PyMemFree(data)
```